# How to setup translation in AEM and integrate it with the MSM setup?

Tags: translation, aem

How to setup translation in AEM and integrate it with the MSM setup?
As an example, how would you achieve:
a. Translate a hit to "www.mysite.com" to
"www.mysite.com/en" and
b. Translate the above  "www.mysite.com/en" to
"/content/mysite/en.html"

Comment: Is it a content translation you are looking for or the url shortening (which can be achieved by etc/maps setup) in AEM.?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is URL shortening and association of the short URLs to the content tree.

One possible approach that I have used on couple of projects is -

- Implement URL shortening using either resourceResolver.map(...) (refer to adobe site [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/configuring/resource-mapping.html)) or URL rewriting (enable this only on publish)
- Next is work on dispatcher, the way dispatcher is configured is to accept the short URL and rewrite it to full content URL so that AEM always receives the request to full path of the content. The mapping in dispatcher/Apache uses pattern matching to match the locale information and then append the incoming URI to the known path in content tree to complete the full URL.

  ```
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule   ^/$  /content/mysite/emea/uk/en_gb/home.html [R]
      RewriteRule ^/en-gb/(.*)$ /content/mysite/emea/uk/en_gb/$1 [PT,L]
  ```

A related article is available [here](http://www.wemblog.com/2012/07/how-to-use-dispatcher-with-mapped.html) for reference.